# How to get the data from special characterized word in where condition?

Tags: java, mysql

I am in trouble with select query

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM blogs where id in(select id from blogers where name=\"" + businessName + "\" ) order by postdate DESC limit " + i + "," + j);
```

as in my blogers table some records have name like rah's, tetra!'t' so this query is not returning me records
what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's wrong here

You're including your values directly in the SQL. **Don't do that.** Use parameterized SQL instead, via a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

That way:

- You don't need to worry about performing any escaping
- You don't need to worry about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- You don't need to worry about conversion issues for dates and times etc
- You separate your code from your data (your SQL will be easier to read, and
  can be extracted to separate resource files if you want, as it will be constant)